# Calculating integral without quadratures

Tags: numerical-analysis, numerical-algorithms

Is there any other options of calculating integral instead of using quadratures? I know that also we can calculate spline function or use monte-carlo method but do you know something else?

Comment: isn't http://scicomp.stackexchange.com a better place for this question?

Comment: Computing an integral *is* quadrature...

Comment: @vonbrand. The Riemann integral is defined by a quadrature, but that doesn't necessarily preclude the existence of an algorithm that computes one without quadratures (though I'm not aware of any).

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use a [computer algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) to compute the integral exactly, symbolically.

See also [Wikipedia's article on symbolic integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_integration).  Wikipedia also has [a list of techniques and computational methods for integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Computation).